# ES6 setter - keep object CLEAN // map params on instance object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, setter, getter-setter

I want to wrap values in an Array, whenever they're set on my object, but I want to keep the "global" object namespace CLEAN

The problem is that I have a list of 8 props that have this same requirement

I don't want the object to be polluted with tons of `get` and `set`, plus the `this._left` to avoid infinite loop when setting the same prop that's monitored by the setter....

For example:

```
class Tree {
    constructor (config) {
        this.left = config.left || [this];
        this.right = config.right || [this];
        this.child = config.child || [this];
        this.parent = config.parent || [this];
        this.somethingElse = config.somethingElse || [this];
        // etc.
    }
}

myObj = new Tree();

myObj.left = 2;
```

I want to ensure that `myObj.next === [2]`

---

My attempt (too polluted):

```
['left', 'right', 'child', 'parent', 'etc', 'adfasdf', 'dsfmkfs', 'previous'].forEach(direction => {
    Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
        set: (val) => {
            if (!Array.isArray(val)) {
                this['_' + prop] = [val]
            } else {
                this['_' + prop] = val;
            }
        },
        get: (val) => {
            return this['_' + prop];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: One improvement would be to use `let props = {}` then store `props['_' + prop] = val` to at least keep the private vars off the global

Comment: What does "keep the global object namespace clean" mean?  And why are you trying to achieve that?  To what end?

Comment: When I log out the instance object, I only want to see props, don't really want to see the nondescript getter and setter functions

Comment: Is there any reason you don't make the getter/setters non-enumerable on either the prototype or on the object itself?  That will take care of logging while not trying to create some complicated way to hide them.  In the future, if you describe the problem you're actually trying to solve, the library of possible solutions covers a much wider range.

Comment: In fact, in your `.forEach()` example loop, those getters and setters are already non-enumerable (since that is the default).  If you put them on the prototype, they'd be even more hidden.

Comment: You can likewise make the `_left` versions of the properties be non-enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have setters/getters without setters/getters. However, you don't necessarily need those underscore-prefixed properties to store the values:

```
['left', 'right', 'child', 'parent', 'etc', 'adfasdf', 'dsfmkfs', 'previous'].forEach(prop => {
    var value = [this];
    Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
        set(val) {
            if (!Array.isArray(val)) {
                val = [val];
            }
            value = val;
        },
        get(val) {
            return value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
});
```